# JAVA Reorganizing While loop in array when considering user input.

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, boolean

My program basically allows the user to enter grades (elements) which are stored in a Gradebook (array). The user also has the option to change the grades (elements) in the Gradebook (array).

My issue is that once the while loop loops and the user is asked **"Make more changes? Enter Yes or No"** If I enter yes, then the user asked which grade to change, is allowed to replace the grade, and the modified gradebook prints. However, if I enter "no" just the gradebook prints. Is there a way I can get the program to print "Good bye!" (signaling the end of the program) if the user enters no? I believe I'm supposed reorganize my code and set a while-loop with boolean = false? But I'm not sure how to get started...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
    System.out.println("Make changes? Enter Yes or No");
    String makeChanges = input.next();



    if (makeChanges.equals("no")) {

        System.out.println("Good bye!");
    }


    while (makeChanges.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
        // Ask user if what grade they would like to change

        //int index = NumberReader.readPositiveInt(input, "Enter the index of the grade to be changed: (1 to " + grades + ") : ", "Invalid index input", index);

        int index = NumberReader.readCappedPositiveInt(input, "Enter the index of the grade to be changed: (1 to " + grades + ") : ", "Invalid index input", numOfGrades);

        System.out.println("Enter grade (limit to two decimal places)" + ": ");
        // offset the index by one
        mogrades[index - 1] = NumberReader.readPositiveDouble(input, "Enter grade " + index + " :",
                "Invalid data entered");

        System.out.println("The Grade book contains: ");

        printArray(mogrades);

        System.out.println("Make more changes? Enter Yes or No");

        makeChanges = input.next();

        System.out.println(makeChanges);

        System.out.println("The Grade book contains: ");

        printArray(mogrades);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Break statements are used to exit loops. You could try this in the while loop:

```
if (makeChanges.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {
    System.out.println("Good Bye!");
    break;
}
```

If you want to exit the entire program, use System.exit(0);

```
if (makeChanges.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {
    System.out.println("Good Bye!");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Here is a simple program demonstrating how this would work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Simple {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String makeChanges = "Yes";

        while (makeChanges.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
            System.out.println("Make more changes? Enter Yes or No:");
            makeChanges = input.next();
            if (makeChanges.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {
                System.out.println("Good Bye!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the output from the command line:

daniel@4.3:StackOverflow$ javac Simple.java

daniel@4.3:StackOverflow$ java Simple

Make more changes? Enter Yes or No:

Yes

Make more changes? Enter Yes or No:

Yes

Make more changes? Enter Yes or No:

No

Good Bye!

Comment: It does exit the program. However, it doesn't read the "Good bye!" message. I did place it in the while loop after makeChanges = input.next();

Comment: Can you re-post your changes so I can see the new code? It should display "Good Bye!", then exit if you copied and pasted the code I entered above.

Comment: couldn't you also just use `return;` to exit the program?

Comment: `return;` would work as well. I've usually used `System.exit(1)` to exit a program, and `return;` to exit a method.

Comment: @Daniel.Schroeder - Okay. I added it as an edit to your program. Let me know if I should post the entire program if that would provide more detail.

Comment: Not sure what happened thought I posted the changes. Here it is again.

Comment: @Coco I re-posted an answer that has more detail, along with my command-line output. Does that solve the issue? Sorry for the delay, I had to run to an event last night and didn't have time to respond to your previous question until this morning!